# add shell script to lambda function on EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that boots a machine on EC2 triggered by a file uploaded on S3 bucket. I would like to run a shell command that is in that machine after the boot, but I failed to do so. Any thoughts of what I can do?

```
import boto3

region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-079e6065f959e151a']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the Amazon EC2 instance, store your script in:

```
/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-boot/
```

Any scripts in that directory will be automatically run each time that the instance boots (or 'Starts').

When the instance has finished its work, it should perform a shutdown with:

```
sudo shutdown now -h
```

This will return the instance to a Stopped state.

See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Comment: Is there a way I can avoid that the script run on every boot, like when I need to do some maintenance on my codes on that machine? This way it will run even if I manually boot the machine

Comment: You could provide a value in the User Data of the instance, which the script inspects and determines whether it should run. The User Data field is simply some information that is passed to the instance -- it can contain anything (not necessarily a script). Alternatively, you could add a Tag to the instance and the script could check the value of the tag (using `DescribeInstances()`) and then decide to run or exit based upon the value of the tag.